# Extending the Miller-Rabin primality test to factor numbers?

Tags: algorithms, prime-factorization

I'm currently using a deterministic version of the Miller-Rabin test (using all bases up to a certain limit). What I'd like to know is if the algorithm can be extended to actually aid in factoring those numbers deemed composite, and if so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If n is a Fermat probable prime base a but not a strong probable prime base a, then either $\gcd((a^d \mod n) − 1, n)$ or (for some r in the above range) $\gcd((a^{2^rd} \mod n) − 1, n)$ will produce a factor of n.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. Only if a number n is a pseudoprime, that is, there is a number a,
such that $a^{n-1}=1 (mod n)$ , but n is composite, then the factors can possibly
be found. Otherwise, Rabins test can only find out, that a number is not prime.

Comment: It is much more difficult to factor a number than deciding whether it is prime. Prime factorization is believed to be a hard problem for which no efficient method exist.